# Invoking setOnCheckedChangeListener without a button click

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I have an application that gives the user the option of using buttons to click yes or no to a series of questions. I want to add handsfree functionality where the user says yes or no and it should access the same code block. I am however stumped as to how I an "virtually" invoke the setOnCheckedChangeListener event of the yes/no buttons to get to the code? Is it possible to make a virtual button call that invokes it? I have attached a snippet of code that hopefully sheds some light.

Code:

```
recognizerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);

public void onResults(Bundle results)
{
    ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

    for (String result : matches)
    {

        switch (result)
        {
            case "yes":
                speech_response_yes=true;
                break;
            case "no":
                speech_response_no=true;
                break;
        }
    }
}

answer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()           {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                if (checkedId == R.id.yesButton || speech_response_yes) 
                {
                  ....perform relevant tasks
                }
```

Comment: You could perhaps move the relevant code to a separate function and then invoke that function from the button click handler as well as the speech handler?

Comment: Yes thats an option, but due to the amount code associated with each subsequent click, was trying to avoid multiples of similar code and instead use the same for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By merely setting the radio buttons as checked, you will invoke the SetOnCheckChangedListener.

```
for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    View o = answer.getChildAt(i);
    if (o instanceof RadioButton) {

      if (o.getId() == R.id.yourButton) { 
         o.setChecked(true);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried it this way and it does not fire the SetOnCheckhangedListener, it just leaves the checkbox checked without firing subsequent code